# Laravel artisan ignoring my app/config/database.php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel

Im trying to complete the quick install guide from Laravel but when using the artisan database tool i got the following error:

```
php artisan migrate --verbose

[PDOException]         
  could not find driver

Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
 PDO->__construct() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php:20
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:41
 Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:128
 Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php:64
 Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:169
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->getConnection() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php:137
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:370
 Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator->repositoryExists() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:95
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php:58
 Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand->fire() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:108
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:244
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:96
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:897
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/project/artisan:59
```

The error on `MySqlConnector` is weird since I have configured Postgres on my `app/config/database.php:`

```
'default' => 'pgsql'
```

Is artisan somehow ignoring my configuration? There is any simple way to force him to use a custom configuration file?

PS: Yes I have my pdo_pgsql included and working (tested).

Comment: Do you have the `php5-pgsql` extension? What os are you running?

Comment: Im running Fedora 18 and I have the latest version of php-pgsql. I tested with `PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "username", "password");` and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `composer update` the artisan start working an using my configurations properly.

Comment: Also make sure you are not using multiple versions of php, this is what I was doing via `phpbrew` and so composer was using the php version installed via phpbrew instead of the system version